# Accessing google cloud compute engine Labels and metadata using ansible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine

I'd like access to compute engine instance metadata and labels I've set via the developer console for use in my ansible scripts. I'd like to be able to use these values like any other ansible gathered variable. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the GCE metadata by using [gce-dynamic-inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/guide_gce.html#gce-dynamic-inventory) script.

You can access the instances with the dynamic inventory like this:

```
- name: Setup web servers
  hosts: tag_webserver
```

Follow the linked instructions on how to setup.